# How do I swap this link out with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, youtube, models

I am trying to take this link..

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lzi_3SM9-o
```

And turn it into this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/4lzi_3SM9-o
```

To do this I need some way to capture `watch?v=` and switch it with `v/`

And I would like to accomplish this in my model with `def tube_link`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regex, just use string replacement:

```
url["watch?v="] = "v/"
```

But *be warned that you might get an index error if you index on something that isn't in the string.* (See [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Replacement,_Substitution_and_Insertion) for more information.)

**Edit:** Something like this might be more readable (*and more reliable*):

```
newUrl = oldUrl.gsub("watch?v=", "v/")
```

Comment: Wow way interesting. Thanks Plat!

Comment: The only problem with your first solution is if `url` doesn't contain `watch?v=` at all you will most likely get an error. ('IndexError: string not matched' for me here, but could depend on your setup).  This makes gsub a better option since it will do nothing if the pattern isn't found.

Comment: @Brett Bender: Ooh, very good point. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

```
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lzi_3SM9-o".gsub("watch?v=", "v/")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should replace double quotes with single quote. It will save your time

```
t1 = Time.now
for i in 1..100000
  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lzi_3SM9-o".gsub("watch\?v=", "v/")
end
t2 = Time.now 
p t2-t1

>ruby test.rb
1.173

t1 = Time.now
for i in 1..100000
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lzi_3SM9-o".gsub('watch\?v=', 'v/')
end
t2 = Time.now 
p t2-t1

>ruby test.rb
0.406
```

1.173 Vs. 0.406

Comment: When you write string in double quotes ruby does string interpolation which slow downs the process.